# tabular columns too wide

Tags: tables, columns

I want to fit the following table on a beamer slide.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K & L & M & N & O & P & Q & R & S & T & U & V & W &   X & Y & Z \\
G & T & U & J & C & P & L & D & O & R & Y & W & X & Z & F & I & V & Q & S & K & A & N & E & M & H & B \\
\end{tabular}
```

However it won't fit, because there is too much space in a single column. If the borders were to perfectly enclose the letters, it would fit.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: You can use `@{}c@{}` instead of `c` to remove the cell spacing. Also try to set `\tabcolsep` to 0pt.

Comment: have you considered to redefine \tabcolsep, the separation between columns. Also you could delete it completely with `{@{}c@{}...}`. A smaller font would probably be better. Maybe using tabularx you can squeeze it to textwidth. A working example would be good. Some beamer themes have a side bar and some don't...

Comment: @MartinScharrer's suggestion should work just fine for you. Note that you can use the `*` notation to make things a little easier on you. You won't have to change 26 occurences. Just go `|@{}c@{}*{25}{|@{}c@{}}|`.

Comment: The @{}c@{} method works! The result fits, but a little bit of spacing would be ok. Is there a way to do a little bit of spacing and keep the *-notation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Modify the length `\tabcolsep` to compress the table horizontally.

```
\documentclass[smaller]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{26}{c|}}
      A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K & L & M & N & O & P & Q & R & S & T & U & V & W &   X & Y & Z \\
      G & T & U & J & C & P & L & D & O & R & Y & W & X & Z & F & I & V & Q & S & K & A & N & E & M & H & B \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I, if I even can, use this hint with `tabular*` environment? I've tried structure `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{cccc}` and table was narrower than text width but `\hline`s were exceeding the table (they have full width).

Comment: @Crowley a `tabular*` or `tabularx` have to have a stretchable column, you are not giving it any, so the environment is confused :-)

Comment: Is it possible to reset the value of `\tabsolsep` afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \resizebox{\linewidth} {\height}{%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}%
    \begin{tabular}{|*{26}{c|}}
      A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K & L & M & N & O & P & Q & R & S & T & U & V & W &   X & Y & Z \\
      G & T & U & J & C & P & L & D & O & R & Y & W & X & Z & F & I & V & Q & S & K & A & N & E & M & H & B \\
    \end{tabular}}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```